# For which $p \in [0, +\infty)$ $\left(\log\left(1 + \frac{e^{px}}{e^x + n}\right)\right)_{n}$ converges uniformly to $0$ on $\mathbb{R}_+$?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

The question is to find  for which $p \geq 0$ the sequence of functions $$f_n: x\in\mathbb{R}_+ \mapsto \log\left(1 + \frac{e^{px}}{e^x + n}\right)$$ converges uniformly to $0$ on $\mathbb{R}_+$ ?

I want to say that for $p \leq 1$ (because we want at least pointwice convergence to $0$). But what's the correct answer for this and how can we prove it?

I know Abel's and Dirichlet's test, but seem's like they're not working here.

Also I found that $\log(1 + x) \leq x$ and seems like we only have to find $p$ such that $\dfrac{e^{px}}{e^x + n}$ converges uniformly to $0$.

Comment: Could you precise what is $n$ please?

Comment: Let us say that $f_n(x) = log(1 + \frac{e^{px}}{e^x + n})$ and we want to prove that $f_n$ converges uniformly to 0.

Comment: Are you interested in the uniform convergence of $f_n$ or $\sum f_n$?

Comment: @Axel of course first one as I wrote in statement.

Comment: alright thank you!

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but $\log$ is it $\ln$ or $\log_{10}$ (it is just for my own knowledge)?

Comment: In higher mathematics it is customary to write $\;\log =\log_e\;$ , what in high school is usually written as $\;\ln\;$ . Any other meaning would usually be explicitly detailed.

Comment: Thank you @DonAntonio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $p>1$, $\dfrac{e^{px}}{e^{x}+n}\rightarrow +\infty$ therefore you can easily see that $f_n$ is not bounded and therefore $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ does not converge uniformly to $0$ on $\mathbb{R}_+$.

---

For $p = 1$, let's determine $||f_n||_{\infty}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

We have for all $x\geq 0$,$f_n'(x)=\dfrac{n e^{x}}{(e^x+n)(2e^x+n)}\geq0$ therefore $f_n$ is increasing on $\mathbb{R}_+$

$\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f_n(x) = \log(2) $ therefore $\lVert f_n \rVert_{\infty}= \log(2) $ thus $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} ||f_n||_{\infty} = \log(2)\neq0$ and therefore $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ does not converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}_+$ to $0$.

---

For $0 \leq p<1$ we have,

$$f_n'(x)=\dfrac{e^{px}((p-1)e^x+np)}{(e^x+n)(e^{px}+e^x+n)}$$

---

So if $0<p<1$,

$$f_n'(x) = 0\iff(1-p)e^x = np \iff x= \log\left(\dfrac{np}{1-p}\right)$$

And you can easily check it is a maximum (the derivative is firstly positive then negative). Therefore,

$$||f_n||_\infty=f_n\left(\log\left(\dfrac{np}{1-p}\right) \right) = \log\left(1+\dfrac{\left(\frac{np}{1-p}\right)^p}{\frac{np}{1-p}+n} \right)$$

But,
$$\dfrac{\left(\frac{np}{1-p}\right)^p}{\frac{np}{1-p}+n} \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\sim} n^{p-1} \left( \frac{\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^p}{1+\frac{p}{1-p}}\right) \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\sim} \alpha_p \dfrac{1}{n^{1-p}} \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0 $$

Therefore,

$$ ||f_n|| \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\rightarrow} \log(1+0) =0$$

So for $0<p<1$,  $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}_+$ to $0$.

---

Finally for $p=0$, we have, by using $|\log(1+x)|\leq |x|$

$$\forall n\in \mathbb{N},\forall x\geq0,|f_n(x)|\leq \dfrac{1}{e^x+n} \leq \dfrac{1}{1+n}$$

Therefore we deduce that,

$$\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, ||f_n||_{\infty} \leq \dfrac{1}{1+n}$$

Hence,

$$ ||f_n|| \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\rightarrow} 0$$

So for $p=0$,  $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}_+$ to $0$.

---

**Conclusion**:

$(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}_+$ to $0$ if and only if $0\leq p <1$.

Comment: Thank you!

But do u know how can we prove that for $p < 0$ this one converges uniformly to 0?

Comment: @Someone, it was not part of your question. But I can give it a try.

Comment: Sorry I mistyped. I mean $p < 1$ which was a part of my question.

Comment: @Someone I edited my answer.